# Error at using GA optimtool "error running optimization. matrix dimensions must agree"

Tags: matlab, optimization

I have nonlinear constrained optimization problem (optimum selection of relay settings). When trying to solve it using a genetic algorithm (using `optimtool` box) it generates this error

> error running optimization. matrix dimensions must agree

although it is solvable using `fmincon` with the same objective and constraints functions.

Comment: So. . . Do the matrix dimensions agree?

Comment: yes i think, i can send the code to check it if you like. also note that the code doesn't include any matrices multiplication.